# Set password for root user in Docker

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

Is it possible to change the root user password in Docker? I have the following lines in my alpine docker:

```
RUN echo “root:Dev123” | chpasswd  
RUN adduser appuser -D  
USER appuser
```

by which I expect the following:

1. Change the root user password
2. Add a new user to the docker, “appuser”
3. Start the Docker container with the “appuser”

Steps 2 & 3 go find and I can see that the Docker is started with the “appuser”

user but it is also possible to run the Docker container as “root” like below

```
docker container run -it --user root myimg:latest sh
```

without being asked for the root password and by that I assume that it is either not possible to change the password or the Docker core somehow knows the new password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root password inside a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721699/root-password-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: The general answer is “you don’t”: Docker containers don’t run remote login services, and paths like `docker exec` imply having root-level access to the host anyways.  Interactive shells in containers are a backup debugging mechanism and not usually a primary way to use Docker.  Also remember that anyone who has the image can run `docker history` on it and see every command that was run in the Dockerfile, which in your case includes that unencrypted password.

Comment: @emix Yes, we want to prevent some users from running the container as root since we have some source code inside the container which we don't want them to be able to see.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have seen this post, my question is how to compile the image so each time they do su or try to login as root a password is being asked. That's why I'm trying to change the root pw.

Comment: And how do users run your image then? For instance one can always override any part of the `docker run` command (the user, the entrypoint etc…). Also if a user has the image locally he can inspect image's content without even running the container.

Comment: @emix I was thinking to restrict access for the docker command only to one user (e.g. DockerAdmin) and compile a binary which actually runs the docker command as DockerAdmin with the docker root privilege. And in case some one grabs the DockerAdmin password, the root password for the docker is still encrypted inside the binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by manually generating /etc/shadow line https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow

and then in RUN step replace first line of that file (which define root password) e.g. using sed:

[sed, replace first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309940/sed-replace-first-line)

Comment: This will not prevent anyone from starting a container as root or executing a command as root on a running container with `docker run/exec -u root` as asked by OP (which is not possible). The other question is:  "why would you ever want to change the root password in a docker image ?". I would never want to use an image where the root password was set to something known.