# how to paste a line instead of a string across many files

Tags: bash

I have 1000 files with txt format, I want to

I want to replace the first line of each file which is "PUT KEYWORDS HERE"
with my keywords which is "XYZ LET DDMIN=0.0 SCFCRT=1.D-10"

any idea

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309940/sed-replace-first-line

Answer (score 0):

sed -i "/PUT KEYWORDS HERE/c\XYZ LET DDMIN=0.0 SCFCRT=1.D-10" path/to/file/*.txt

Comment: it didn't work , does not add anything

Comment: are you sure you aren't path/to/file wrong?

Comment: 100%, I am also in the same place as the files are `sed: 1: "/Users/admin/Desktop/te ...": command a expects \ followed by text`

Comment: then try this | sed -i "/PUT KEYWORDS HERE/c\XYZ LET DDMIN=0.0 SCFCRT=1.D-10" *.txt

Comment: also sorry for the late response

Comment: it is also not working `sed: 1: "TW112256-1.txt": invalid command code S` this is one of the file name

Comment: are there any other files in that folder other that .txt?

Comment: no there is nothing else

Comment: well then i don't know. By my testing the command should replace all text in all file named .txt with the text PUT KEYWORDS HERE to XYZ LET DDMIN=0.0 SCFCRT=1.D-10. Unless the .txt files contains strings of data that is not readable as text. Then it prints out a error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(ls -lA ./path | grep -v "total" | awk {'print $NF'})

for file in ${files[*]}
do
    sed -i -e '1s/PUT KEYWORDS HERE/XYZ LET DDMIN=0.0 SCFCRT=1.D-10/' ./path/$file
done
```